# Mature compilers based on ANTLR v3

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, antlr, d

Are there mature (and open-source, since I want to read the code) language implementations based on ANTLR? I don't really want to read the code for a DSL, or language that targets C/C++ as output. What I'm after is a project that either targets assembler or bytecode for a fully featured general purpose programming language (of any paradigm).

BTW: If they used the D target, that would be perfect!

Comment: nothing? I can't believe that! Surely someone out there can direct me to an open source project doing good things with ANTLR?

Comment: There is nothing magically special about "mature compilers" related to ANTLR that you won't find in DSLs or "high-level" (to C/C++) compilers. The task of deriving an abstract syntax tree from a text file is the same for DSLs as it is for "real" compilers. It is afterwards (type-checking/inference, optimization, code generation) where the heavy lifting starts.

Answer (score 2):

It may not suit your exact needs, but [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx) uses ANTLR for its HQL parsing. It is open source, and mature.